# why should one register listener first and call emit method next in node.js?? can't we reverse the order and still be able to work?

Tags: node.js

Why is order of listener should be on top of emitter?

```
const EventEmitter=require('events');
const emitter=new EventEmitter();
   
 //Register a Listener
    
      emitter.on('messageLogged',function(){
        console.log('Listener Called');
        })
//Raise an event
    
    emitter.emit('messageLogged');
```

Comment: It would help to find the right answer if you explain why you ask the question. Maybe because you think the order should not matter? And if so, why?
Are you working on something that requires you do emit the event before you get to subscribe/listen?

Comment: @roychri Hi, No I'm not working on any thing. I'm just learning node and came across events module and stuck asking the the question "why is order important here, when both(event raiser and the listener ) are on same module".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you need to subscribe a listener to the event before you emit an event.

The idea is that when you call `emit` it will call functions you attached to the event. If there is no function it will call nothing. You can not call a function that is attached in the future for an event that you `emit` at the moment.

Comment: So when we call emit it will look for functions that we attached that to, right? so what if the listener is registered after the emit is called?? doesn't emit look the code below it for registered listeners?? so you mean emit only look on top ?  Thank you for the response :)

Comment: Yep, it will call only the functions that you have attached via `on` call.  It does not look on the top. It just uses the functions you attached. It depends on timing, it is a matter of  `when` the `emit` is called rather than `where` in your code you call it.

Comment: You confused me with your last comment. I knew emit will look for functions that it's event is registered or attached with! but I'm questioning about order here. so are you saying order is not important ?? so listener can be registered even after emit is called?? I'm bit confused with your last comment by your words "it depends on timing, it is a matter of when the emit is called rather than where in your code" Thanks alot for the response :)

Comment: Order in the time matters. In your example, you need to call the `emit` after `on` call because it is sync code. If that would be `async` code the order in your code may differ from the order in which it is called on a timeline, e.g. setTimeout(... , 50) will be called sooner than setTimeout(... , 100)
The listener can be registered after the emit is called but it won't receive an event from the past. It will be called with the next `emit` call. 
Does this helps?

Comment: Thanks alot for the help! Yes it does help!